# Post a URL TO twitter?

Tags: twitter

Is it possible to post a URL to twitter through their API? Ideally to then be able to control any description/thumbnail for say a youtube video like you can on facebook? For example simply appending a youtube URL to a tweet will display the video but when you click through to view it the description has been pulled through from the Youtube page rather than being user defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter does not allow you to edit the descriptions the way Facebook does.